# Primefaces Ajax calls taking a lot time

Tags: ajax, jsf, time, primefaces

Hi I am working on JSF using Primefaces 3.5.  Following is a code snippet for switching from one page to other page using menuitems, I am trying to use ajax calls to avoid page flicking while moving from one page to other.

Following is the code from my xhtml file :

```
<p:menubar styleClass="brzero borderb">
      <p:menuitem value="Student" action="#{studentMB.show('menu')}" ajax="true" />
      <p:menuitem value="Users" action="#{usersMB.show('menu')}" ajax="true" />
      <p:menuitem value="Departments" action="#{departmentMB.show('menu')}" ajax="true" />
</p:menubar>
```

A used managed bean  show action function goes as

```
public String show(String mode) {               
    if (mode.equals("menu")){
        selectStudent=null;
    init();
        return "studentList.jsf";
    }
    else if (mode.equals("list")){
        return "welcome.jsf";
    }
    else {
        clone(selectStudent, oldStudent);
        return "studentEdit.jsf";
    }                   
}
```

The code is working fine on localhost tomcat server, but when deployed on remote server accessed via internet, these calls are taking a large amount of time around 15-20 secs. I tried on two three different network servers to check if this can be network/DNS issue but the problem persists on all the servers.

Any idea/help what can be the reason for this , or is their anything I am doing wrong, I know the ajax must be used to serve partial requests or to update sections, but what can be the solution for page switching ..

Comment: page load time depends on what code you have in jsf files you are trying to load. do they contain any js/css reference which do not exists.

Comment: No, I have been using just one css, no external js, and as I said these are working very fine on localhost servers, but when accessed through remote severs they causes the issue.. and my jsf pages contains simple primefaces datatable, commandbuttons and some text fields.....

Comment: can you check database connection/ data retrieving time?

Comment: I did that , one thing I will like to state that when I change ajax="true" to ajax="false" in xhtml file and return "studentList.jsf"; to return "studentList.jsf?faces-redirect=true"; in managedbean , they are not taking any time, but the screen flicks between page navigations

Comment: You should use JSF Navigation.

Answer (score 0):

This is should be done by JSF Navigation. See below solution:

Add this in your f`aces-config.xml`

```
<navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/index.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>menu</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/studentlist.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

It says, whenever the outcome is "menu" just redirect to `studentlist.xhtml.`

Now, update your `main.xhtml` to

```
<p:menubar styleClass="brzero borderb">
      <p:menuitem value="Student" action="menu"/>
</p:menubar>
```

If someone selects Student menu,it will automatically redirect to `studentlist.xhtml.`

Try it !

Comment: Thanks Makky for the explanation and your efforts, I will be trying it , just one quick question over here, actually my managed bean function (show()) is intended to perform some action before redirection such as initialization, calling some object cloning logics , so where shud I then put them into the sequence u mentioned. please see my updated show method in the question above